# How to create new folder of playlists in Deezer

Tags: deezer

Some time ago, Deezer added a feature allowing grouping playlists and albums into folders. There's still a note on this feature in [Deezer Developers](http://developers.deezer.com/guidelines/core_concepts#mymusic) site. For a long time there was also a "create new folder" button in application's left panel.

Has the feature been removed? Why?

I can still listen, view and edit existing folders, but I cannot add new one.